# Best way to exclude some properties from binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

One of my classes has some properties that I want model binder to always ignore them.

Currently I'm using `[Bind(Exclude ="")]` in the action methods, like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "prop1, prop2, prop3")] BusinessModel model)
```

This class has been used in several action methods. Do I have to manually exclude them, or there is a better way?

I should note in this particular class, they're navigation properties.

Comment: Use a view model rather than your data model - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem using centralized code is to override `BindModel` of `DefaultModelBinder` and exclude the properties which you don't want to bind.

```
public class CustomDataBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(BusinessModel))
        {
            HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
            string name = request.Form.Get("Name");
            return new BusinessModel
            {
                Name = name
            };                
        }
        else
        {
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
    }
}
```

And then register it at `Global.asax` in `Application_Start()`.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(BusinessModel), new CustomDataBinder());
```

In above case I have used `BusinessModel` as described as below -

```
public class BusinessModel
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To test, I have created a simple view -

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.BusinessModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostData", "Home"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.prop1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

When view renders, I entered some data in both the editors - 
[image]

When I hit create button, the entered value in `Prop1` editor was not binded -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[ramiramilu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30680749/3627970) is great, but I would like to add a minor detail to it.

It's probably better to return `base.BindModel` with a new [BindingContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbindingcontext(v=vs.118).aspx) which excludes the properties to be ignored instead of returning a `BusinessModel` object out straight.

This lets the DefaultModelBinder's [ModelState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbindingcontext.modelstate(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext.ModelState) validation mechanism to kick in.

```
public class CustomDataBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(BusinessModel))
        {
            BindAttribute bindAttribute = new BindAttribute
            {
                Exclude = "prop1, prop2, prop3"
            };

            // create new property filter where only properties which are not exluded in the above bindAttribute are bound
            Predicate<string> newPropertyFilter = propertyName => bindAttribute.IsPropertyAllowed(propertyName) && bindingContext.PropertyFilter(propertyName);         

            ModelBindingContext newBindingContext = new ModelBindingContext()
            {
                //bind default ModelMetaData
                ModelMetadata = bindingContext.ModelMetadata,

                //set to new property filter which exludes certain properties
                PropertyFilter = newPropertyFilter,

                //bind default ModelState
                ModelState = bindingContext.ModelState,

                //bind default ValueProvider
                ValueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            };
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, newBindingContext);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
    }
}
```